# Web DevelopmentL: PHP & Apache

Tags: apache, webserver, tomcat7

Im trying to write a blog using PHP,I downloaded Php 5, Notepad++ And Apache Tomecat 7.

The problem is that I dont know where to save the .Php files I wrote so I can open them using the Apache Server.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tomcat is for java, you don't need that for php

Comment: You need the Apache httpd server and not Tomcat. For a pre-configured-package, see http://www.apachefriends.org/ .

Comment: @Sirko, ,NimChimpsky Thanks for answering. Can I use XAMPP? is it good for security?

Comment: I would not recommend it for a productive system, but if you're just after testing in a local network, it's fine.

Comment: @Sirko, Why is that? what do you recommend me to use? (the securiy thing is very important for my projoct. Its my final project in some course.)

Comment: For example, the MySQL configuration omits a password for root access from localhost. If you really have to focus on security, you should maybe rely on another package or read more about securing a server. XAMPP is a testing or local system and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Tomcat server that is for Java applications.

You're best bet is to install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (on Windows) or [LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/) (on Linux) then you have all the tools including MySQL to start coding. The Apache server comes preconfigured for use with PHP.

If you're coding on Windows then WAMP is a single install package.

There are plenty of tutorials to help you out, but essentially your Apache server will have a web root directory named "www" in it's configuration file. That's where you place all of your php and html files, etc.

**[Edit]**

Reading some of the comments, the recommendation for WAMP or XAMP for your *local development*. You can run all this comfortably on a laptop. When it comes to releasing your application to the world you will probably want to pick a Hosting service that supports PHP and will take care of all the server configuration for you. You'll just be copying up your PHP code files and creating the databse.

Comment: Uh, sorry Im a begginer trying to learn a web-development language, and I read in some website that I need Tomcat. I Downloaded XAMPP, is it the same?

Comment: It's gives you the same features, so you can pick either XAMP or WAMP. It's a matter of preference. I happen to use WAMP and it's easy to get started with.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. Secondly, do you recommend me one of these? this blog is my final project for some course and I need it to be as secure and good as possible. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that WAMP,XAMP or LAMP are just a collection of the same underlying components (i.e. Apache + MySQL). Therefore your security considerations are the same for both. You'll have to lock down your Apache server and your MySQL server the same regardless of which option you choose. As a starting point [here's a tutorial](http://www.leifohman.com/pgSamples/SecureWamp.aspx) that may help you understand what's involved in securing a server.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll read this tutorial and try to start writing my blog using XAMPP. Thanks again.